# Pycharm function call in Python code doesn't return anything

Tags: python, pycharm, function-call

I am currently learning about Python and decorator functions. I found the code below on a tutorial site. When I try to run it in Pycharm, the function call at the bottom does not return anything (I need to use print instead). Why is that the case? Thank you.

```
def uppercase_decorator(function):
    def wrapper():
        func=function()
        make_uppercase=func.upper()
        return make_uppercase
    return wrapper

@uppercase_decorator
def say_hi():
    return "hello there"

say_hi()
```

Comment: It does return, it just doesn't print the return value to your console.

Comment: Pycharm is different from Python IDE or terminal. To print the value, you need to use the `print` function in python.

Comment: If you want an output you have to print it.

Comment: Thank you all very much. Understood. I am just a beginner so apologies for it being so basic.